# Sort an NSArray with custom order

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary object that contains a list of menu items for an iPhone app. The desired order of the menu items is not alphabetical so the standard way of **sorting the keys** is not really an option. My dictionary is as follows and is initialized in the desired order (I understand that dictionaries are not sorted--I need to sort the array of keys in this order):

```
    menuDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [menuDict setObject:@"Main Menu" forKey:@"EntryViewController"];
    [menuDict setObject:@"States Lookup" forKey:@"AllStatesViewController"];
    [menuDict setObject:@"Favorites" forKey:@"FavoritesViewController"];
    [menuDict setObject:@"Help" forKey:@"HelpViewController"];
    [menuDict setObject:@"About" forKey:@"AboutViewController"];
```

How can I get a list of keys and sort them in the same order as this dictionary ? Thanks!

Comment: "sort them in the same order as this dictionary" does not make sense because the keys in a dictionary are not ordered.

Comment: The items in the dictionary are in the order defined by the app requirements. Unfortunately, the required order is not alphabetical. This is the problem

Comment: @Pheepster No, a dictionary doesn't have any order.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I am trying to establish an order that is not standard. The order I wish to achieve happens to be the order of the above listed dictionary

Comment: You need to define that order separate to the dictionary...

Comment: Create an array of keys and put them in the order you prefer.

Comment: @HotLicks--how would I put the keys into a custom order. This is what I am stuck on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, `NSDictionary` does not save the order in which items are added. For this you should use a `NSArray`.

Here is an example of how you can us it:

```
NSArray *menuArray = @[
   @{ @"Title" : @"Main Menu", @"Controller" : @"EntryViewController"},
   @{ @"Title" : @"States Lookup", @"Controller" : @"AllStatesViewController"},
   @{ @"Title" : @"Favorites", @"Controller" : @"FavoritesViewController"},
   @{ @"Title" : @"Help", @"Controller" : @"HelpViewController"},
   @{ @"Title" : @"About", @"Controller" : @"AboutViewController"},
];
```

This way you can even add an extra key in the dictionary for the order, so you can sort it later if you need to insert  items later in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of keys and another of values. Then use the `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:` method to create your dictionary. Then you don't need to do any additional sorting because you have the array of keys.

As has been pointed out, you can't get the ordered keys back from the dictionary so you need to use the original array of keys for your order information.

Comment: Definitely better with the edit. The real problem is that the OP is using the wrong data structure in the first place.